# Facing Ambiguous column reference error while inserting into a hive table

Tags: hive

## My main table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user(language STRING,snapshot_time STRING,products STRUCT<id:STRING,name:STRING>,item STRUCT<quantity:ARRAY<STRUCT<name:STRING>>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/input/sample';
```

This is my main table, from which I'm trying to retrieve specific fields and insert into "user_prod_info" table. But, while inserting data using "Insert into" command, I'm facing the below error :

**FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10007]: Ambiguous column reference text in q**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user_prod_info ( 
temp_row_num INT,
language STRING,
snapshot_time STRING,
id STRING,
prod_name STRING,
user_name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
NULL DEFINED as "null"
stored as textfile;
```

## My insert command :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user_prod_info
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY products.id ORDER BY snapshot_time DESC) AS temp_row_num,
language,
snapshot_time,
products.id,
products.name,
A.name
FROM user as raw 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(item.quantity) quantity as A
) q WHERE temp_row_num == 1;
```

This command is unable to retrieve the field from the specific table because we have two "name" fields. one is in "products" and the other is in "A".

I tried creating alias for "A.name as name1". I'm able to insert the data without errors. But, one record is storing in 3 rows with some nulls in it.

I got stuck over here. Can anyone please help me out regarding this...

Comment: It is because your data contains \n (newline). Try to put all json object in the single line

Comment: Multi line JSON is not supported: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-16829

Comment: I think, the problem is not with the json, because I have removed one of the ambiguous columns and tried to load the data into that table. The data insertion is proper without any nulls.

Comment: But, when I try to keep the ambiguous column by giving some alias name, then it is inserting one record into 3 rows with nulls in it.

Comment: I don't know, why this insert is behaving strangely while trying to use ambiguous column by giving some alias name

Comment: You have fixed ambiguous column correctly. Check what your select returns

Comment: Unnecessary spaces have been added in the return data of  select query. In the actual Json, there are no spaces in between. Due to this, the spaces are loaded as null in the table and taking 3 to 4 rows for one record

Comment: I believe it is not spaces, it should be something else: newlines or TABs, spaces should work fine, please double check this

Comment: And question should be renamed to something like Rows splitted when selecting json, this is not an issue with ambiguous column names, you fixed it right

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the ambiguous adding an alias for one of the column names like this

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user_prod_info
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY products.id ORDER BY snapshot_time DESC) AS temp_row_num,
language,
snapshot_time,
products.id,
products.name as prod_name,
A.name
FROM user as raw 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(item.quantity) quantity as A
) q WHERE temp_row_num == 1;
```

Comment: I have already added alias name to "A.name as name1". It has inserted properly without any ambiguity. But one record is occupying 3 to 4 rows with nulls in it.

Comment: @fervent, you should provide input/output data in order to get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using same name "temp_row_num" in 2 commands. So please this name in 2nd command as "temp_row_num_new". Full 2nd query is below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE user_prod_info
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY products.id ORDER BY snapshot_time DESC) AS 
temp_row_num_new,
language,
snapshot_time,
products.id,
products.name,
A.name
FROM user as raw 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(item.quantity) quantity as A
) q WHERE temp_row_num_new == 1;
```